# How do I draw a simple line and a rectangle using Kivy in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I simply want to let the program draw a line and a rectangle in a window using Kivy. Position and properties don't matter for now.

I'm new to Python and very new to Kivy und I've never worked with a GUI before. I tried searching on multiple websites but none seemed to have a solution for my problem.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label

class KivyTest(App):
    self.pos = 12
    self.size = 6

    def build(self):
        with self.canvas:
            Line(points=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
            Color(1, 0, 0, .5, mode='rgba')
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

KivyTest = KivyTest()
KivyTest.run()
```

I expect 12 to be the position of the rectangle and 6 its size, but the error message "name 'self' is not defined" is printed out. There's obviously something crucial I don't understand. I'd also love it, if there is someway to use a .kv file for my problem, I'm only using a .py file, since .kv didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first lines of your definition you have

```
class KivyTest(App):
    self.pos = 12
    self.size = 6
```

and `self` does not exist there; in order to initialize those values you have to do:

```
class KivyTest(App):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = 12
        self.size = 6
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I decided to implement your last option for now. Now I get a new error message: 'KivyTest' object has no attribute 'canvas' Unfortunately I don't have any experience with canvas, so I might want to try something else.

Comment: Seems like an `app` doesn't have a canvas; a Widget does.

Comment: Don't use the last option, use the first one that @Tordek suggested. The last one overrides the normal kivy pos and size objects (these are descriptors defined at class level), which you don't want to do.

Comment: Good point, I didn't know they were special; I've amended my answer